# Spring error in resolving xsd schema

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd

I'm trying to use Spring Security module, but I get an XML Validation error regarding the security xsd file.

This is the spring-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">



    <!--  Security....................................... -->

    <security:http security="none" pattern="/resources/**"/>
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('Admin')" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/welcome" logout-url="/logout" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/welcome"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="hashPwd" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
            />
    </security:http>


    <security:authentication-manager>
       <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="controlloUtente">
         <security:password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />  
      </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

And this is the exception I get (I obviously checked and the file exists!):

```
19/06/2015 12:32:38 - WARN  - (SimpleSaxErrorHandler.java:48) - Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 16; columnNumber: 58; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:99)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:433)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:347)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4166)
```

I'm behind proxy but I configured it and the other xsd got resolved, so I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Do you have the sping-security.jar in your buildpath?

Comment: Of course I have. The only thing that gives me some doubt is that all the other files begin with `<xsd>` while this one with `<xs>` tag.

Comment: There are many question about this already, check your dependencies versions (also check [that](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-config) "To start using the security namespace in your application context, you need to have the spring-security-config jar on your classpath")

Comment: Do you have the `spring-security-config` jar...

Answer (score 0):

maybe this code will help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<security:http auto-config="true">

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.do"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout.do"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/fail2login.do"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/json/*.do"
        access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.do"
        default-target-url="/home.do" authentication-failure-url="/fail2login.do" />

    <security:session-management>
        <security:concurrency-control
            max-sessions="1" />
    </security:session-management>
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout.do"
        delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service
            data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select userName, password, status from User where userName=?"
            authorities-by-username-query="select us.userName, ur.userRoleName from User us, UserRole ur   
            where ur.userName =?  " />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```